# Vertical text always remain same distance from side of image

Tags: html, css

I have an image with some vertical text giving credit on the photo.

I want to ensure that the text always stays **outside the image** when it becomes *responsive*.

I am trying to put the text just outside the image, and at the bottom right of the image.

Here is the snippet

```css
section {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
img {
  width: 93%;
}
.vertical-text {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: left top 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform-origin: left top 0;
  -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
  -moz-transform-origin: left top 0;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="vertical-text">Photo Credit</div>
  <img src="http://www.wrestlingwithpopculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/BRET-HART-06b.jpg">
</div>
```

Comment: So the text should be on the photo or not...it's unclear? If off the picture...where should it be?

Comment: the text should be off the photo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go, I think this is close.

Note the image width calculation. In general the text will have a line-height (which once rotated becomes teh width) of 1.2em...so if we make the image 100% *less* that amount, there should always be room for the text block.

```css
.section {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: pink;
}

img {
  width: calc(100% - 1.2em);
  display: block;
}

.img-wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.vertical-text {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  transform: translate(100%, 50%) rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: top left;


}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  
  <div class="img-wrap">
<div class="vertical-text">Photo Credit</div>
    <img src="http://www.wrestlingwithpopculture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/BRET-HART-06b.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/pdkb1Lf5/7/)

Comment: Sorry that was left over from a test I'll take it out. It's not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood right. you want the text to be outside of the photo to the right

to `.vertical_text`  add this   `width:0%;white-space:nowrap;`

EDIT :

on mobile with media query make the img smaller. 85% instead of 93%. that should do it. you need to have enough space for the text to fit in. also you could make the font-size of the text smaller if you want. but changing the img size should be enought.

To align the text on the bottom it's a bit tricky because of the rotation.
use this
at `.section` add `position:relative`
at `.vertical_text` add `position:absolute;bottom:68px;right:0`
where `bottom:68px` is the actual width of your text

Comment: i think this is good, but when the screen gets to mobile size it moves into the image

Comment: also do u know how to have the text at the bottom of the image?